# Call Javascript funtion from angular2 application generated with angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some troubles with calling a JS script from TypeScript. I tried all examples from the internet but are not working in my case.

Comment: Please provide some code of your use case, otherwise we will not be able to help you more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's acually pretty simple.

Suppose you have a JS script, called `myScript.js`, and a .ts file of your Angular2 application, called `myComponent.component.ts`.
The two files, in this example, will be in the same folder.

Now from your .ts files, you can simply import the .js file this way:

```
import * as myScript from './myScript';
```

and then use your import as such, for example `myScript.doSomething()`

**EDIT 1:**

To further clarify, you need to `export` things in your js files, otherwise they will expose nothing to their caller.

For example, your myScript.js file should be like:

```
export default {

   function doSomething() {
      console.log('i am doing something amazing');
   }

}
```

You can find more info on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) mdn page.

Comment: After I made the changes I receive some error: ../myScript.js  is not a module.

Comment: I'll post an edit to make you clear how your .js need to be

Comment: Module parse failed: 'function' can not be used as shorthand property. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  - the error showed after I made the update. My function has just a console.log()  as yours

Comment: Okay, seems fair. Last try we can do without your code (that you should share because we are fairly blind here) is to utilize System.import, like this:
System.import(''./myScript').then(loaded => {
      loaded.doSomething();
}

Comment: The solution for the problem was to just export every function. I just changed to `export function doSomething() { ... }`. It's strange why it's not working your example.